# Proof: Splitting triangle

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that, if ABC is a triangle with Angle A= 90 Degrees, Angle B=30 Degrees and C= 60 Degress, and W is the midpoint of the hypotenus, then the line connetcting W to A divides ABC into an equaliteral triangle and an isosceles triangle.

[image]

This is how my thought process went:

First I looked at the conditions:

- Equilateral triangle: all sides equally long.
- Isosceles triangle: two sides equally long.

Now to check these conditions are met after splitting the triangle I need to figure out how the line ZA splits it.

I know that:

$z^2=x^2+y^2$

$\frac{z}{2}=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Now here I got stuck. So I tried another approach:

Sin Cos and Tan with $\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right\}$, to figure out that the length of ZA and then I calculated the angles which was 30 and 60. Having all lengths and angles I was able to verify that the hypohesis was correct.

**Problem:** I do not believe this would be accepted as a proof!

Could someone please comment on this:

This is what I think is the problem( when I stopped using variables and started using values I went from a general proof to a specific case, hence it does not show that the proof would hold in all cases.

Also could someone please provide a good simple proof to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If W is the midpoint of BC
for *any* right triangle,
then |WA| = |WB| = |WC|.

This is because,
if you draw a semicircle
centered on W
with BC as its radius,
then,
since BAC is a right angle,
A is on that semicircle.

Since |WA| = |WB|,
AWB is isosceles.
This holds for *any*
right triangle.

Since |WA| = |WC|,
AWC is an isosceles triangle.
Again,
this holds for any right triangle.

Now, we make use of
the fact that
$\angle$ ACB = 60.
We get
 $\angle$ WAC = $\angle$ WCA = 60.
Therefore,
$\angle$ AWC
= 180-60-60 = 60,
so WAC is equilateral.

Answer (score 1):

I would go to a more geometrical proof.

$ABC$ is a right triangle. Hence it lies on a circle centered at the middle of the hypotenus. So $ZC=ZA$ is isosceles and $\widehat{ZCA}=\widehat{ZAC}=60°$. The last angle of $\widehat{AZC}$ is also equal to $60°$ as the sum of the angles of a triangle is equal to $180°$ and finally $ZAC$ is equilateral.

The other triangle is isosceles as $ZA=ZB$.